# What's the idiomatic equivalent of "at the top of one's lungs", if there is one?

Tags: english-to-german, idiom

I'd like to translate the following sentence into German:

> She screamed at the top of her lungs.

But I have a feeling that Google Translate's result, "Sie schrie an der Spitze der ihre Lungen" is way too literal. Is there a German equivalent of the expression, "at the top of [my/your/her] lungs"?

Comment: I would use something like `mit aller Kraft schreien`, but there could be something more exact with this meaning as well.

Comment: @tofor also possible: _aus voller Brust_

Comment: @Crissov Isn't that more reserved for singing?

Comment: @tofro Ich würde es auch für Schreien akzeptieren, habe aber keine tatsächlichen Vorkommen überprüft.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You seem to be needing some anatomy details: How about

> Sie schrie aus vollem Hals

Not quite the lungs, but close. And a common idiom in German.

Comment: +1 or 'aus voller Kehle' would also be possible. Those are much more common than 'aus voller Lunge' wich sounds odd to me

Comment: Thanks! *Aus vollem Hals* is also anatomically more correct - You don't yell with your lungs ;)

Comment: If you search through Google for "schrie aus voller Lunge", you get about 25 results. But if you search for "schrie aus vollem Hals", you get about 1820 results. So, the latter version seems to be more prevalent. However, "schrie aus voller Lunge" isn't incorrect, as Duden seems to OK such a wording.

Comment: @Tobio'Bobi Actually *aus voller Kehle* would rather be used for singing than for screaming.

Comment: I've changed this to the accepted answer since it seems more people prefer this one.

Answer (score 9):

[Pons](http://en.pons.com/translate?q=top+of+lungs&l=deen&in=en&lf=en) suggests:

> Sie schrie sich die Lunge aus dem Leib.

This is also a common idiom and I don't think you get closer to the original.

Comment: Must disagree - while the original phrase emphasizes the volume, not necessarily any length, *sich die Lunge aus dem Leib schreien* indicates volume plus a certain time of shouting / screaming / yelling action.

Comment: @stephie: [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Lunge) does not share your disagreement.

Comment: @stephie I agree with you.

Answer (score 6):

A correct translation would be:

> "Sie schrie sich die Seele aus dem Leib".

It might not be an literal translation, but it is a common expression which is also applicable in your case.